# Issue with passing 0 in an array generated by JS/PHP Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script written in JQuery that makes an AJAX call to a PHP function. That function returns an array of data depending on the data sent to it.

At the front end I have radio buttons with data attributes on them determining which index of the array to fetch and then output to the screen.

The issue is that it won't use `0` as a number to fetch. By starting the array with a blank value and increasing the number to fetch by one, everything works as it should.

My question is, why won't `0` be parsed by the Javascript to fetch the right data. My theory is that is has something to do with `0` being identical to false, however, I'd expect 1 to be similar and return true.

I've tried using `parseInt(0, 10)` when fetching the data. I also tried using `!isNan(parseInt(0, 10))` to try and negate the false value.

A basic version of what I am using is below. I've left out the AJAX call as that works fine and I don't think that is the problem.

html

```
<input type="radio" data-description-id="0" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" data-description-id="1" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" data-description-id="2" name="radio" />
// Etc
```

javascript

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(event) {
    var evt = event;
    if($(evt.currentTarget).data('description-id')) {
        var $_correctDescriptionID = parseInt($(evt.target).data('description-id'), 10),
        $_injuryDescriptionContainer = $('.icc__injury-description span');
        $_injuryDescriptionContainer.text($_injuryDescriptions[$_correctDescriptionID]);
    }

    console.log($_correctCompensationAmount);
    console.log($_correctDescriptionID);

});
```

Example Array

```
{
    [0] => "Description one"
    [1] => "Description two"
    [2] => "Description three"
}
```

Expected results are as follows:
- When clicking on a radio button it would set the text of p tag to the corresponding text in the array.
- Therefore if you choose input 2, you'd get "Description two" etc.

It fetches the correct data, however the first value is ignored, essentially the `[0]` in the array. So clicking on radio button 1 returns undefined, but clicking on radio button 2, you get "Description two".

Comment: 0 is a false-y value, so the condition here `if($(evt.currentTarget).data('description-id'))` will simply not be true if the current target is that first radio button with data-description-id="0".

Comment: _Small Note_ `var evt = event;` ? WHY. Bought more memory than you need and you are trying to make sure you use the most you possibly can?

Comment: Come on, @RiggsFolly - `evt` is MUCH easier to type than `event`

Comment: @WillardSolutions So why not do `function(evt)` ? Or `function(e)`

Comment: It was a joke @RiggsFolly

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't get that :) @WillardSolutions

Comment: Based on the above, and my further research would it be better to determine if the attribute exists (as that was intention) using something like `$(evt.target).filter('[data-description-id]')` ... or is there a simpler way? @RiggsFolly slightly off topic from my question, but can you explain why it would use more memory? Still in the throws of learning vanilla js/jquery and am just curious!?!?